# Need help to search image from a folder

Tags: node.js, image, ubuntu

I have a lot of images on a ubuntu server. Is there any process to search images from that server, like google image search does. I have searched a little bit, I think term is "Reverse Image Search". Right now I was trying if I can do this by NodeJS. I got several library [Look Same](https://github.com/gemini-testing/looks-same) and [PixelMatch](https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch). As I have about 5k images so I think those will be slower process. I can use those for 10-50 image. Is there any way I can do those using NodeJS or any other service of Ubuntu?

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer about what you are searching for. Are you looking for cars? Or yachts? Or are you looking for 2 images that are similar to each other? Or images that are similar to one you already have? By *"similar"*, do you mean similar size? Or shape? Or colour? Or number of objects?...

Comment: I have a pile of images and I need have a image to search similar image from that pile. Like amazon app does. You just snap a images and search for that product using that image.